# is it okay to use the word "upgrade" in this case?

Tags: meaning

In my company, we found that one of the software that comes with operating system is old and is causing the issue, we thought to replace that software with latest version but that did not happen, so we installed latest version of that software in a separate folder and then using it without disturbing the one that comes with operating system.

Can we say that we upgraded the software or we cant say as we did not disturb that but installed a new latest new version separately?

What is the word we can say in this case?

Comment: You need to know if upgrading and installing a new version are the same.  Many software offer the users the 'upgrade option', and it will be a new version too.

Comment: I did not click on upgrade option, but I installed new version of the same software separately

Comment: Upgrading usually means changing to a better version, program, device, car, whatever. If anyone is still using the previous one they haven't upgraded. Updating means getting a newer one, which sounds like what you have done. You can update or upgrade either in place or by replacing. You have both the updated and original versions on your system. I would say you have updated if you are using the new version, even if the old one is still in place (as a backup?)

Comment: You have **upgraded** the software, even if the previous version still exists. Or you can say you **replaced it**. Or you can say you **installed** a new version. Or you **updated** it. They all sound right.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but if one thing has multiple meanings, users can misunderstand right?

Comment: Does it matter, as long as people know you are using the lastest version of the software? You can say "we are using the latest version of X."

Comment: Yes I think it matters because the software that is coming by default with operating system means that software can be used by other software as a dependency, so people might get doubt that as you upgraded the version that caused issue to another software. But if we are clear that we did not disturb the original software, then they wont think of any other issues and they wont blame us that that is because of this